# Tor broswer time zone leak java version

Tags: time

First of all thanks for the time spent on this project, I really appreciate! From where can I download the version who shows/leaks timezone and date? I tried installing older versions but all of them are showing GMT +0000 (UTC)...or better is there a way to change the time that Tor browser shows?